# How to see JSON response for REST service?

Tags: rest-api, rest, apexrest, rest-service, restresource

How I can see what the JSON response looks like for a REST service that looks like the one below? I guess I'm looking for the actual steps of what I need to do to see the JSON response.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/BP_Routes/*')
global with sharing class BP_Routes {

    @HttpPost //Method name
    //Check for User Authentication based on UserName and Password from external system
    global static ResponseWrapper BP_Routes(string username) {

        String strStatusMsg = '';//Holds the status message
        Integer isSuccessRes;//Holds the success response '1' or '0'
        list<Routewrapper> lstRteWrap = new list<Routewrapper>();
        list<personRoutesWrapper> lstPrsnWrap = new list<personRoutesWrapper>();
        ...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can head over [Salesforce Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) and use the REST Utility to test the endpoint .

[image]

Your endpoint to test will be

```
/services/apexrest/BP_Routes
```

Also looks like the method is accepting a string parameter ,so you will need to select post and then the JSON input is

```
{
  "username" : "test"
}
```

The response will tell you the JSON structure .Also just by looking into the ResponseWrapper class you will know the structure of the JSON .

Answer (score 5):

IN exec anonymous simply type:

```
system.debug(BP_Routes.BP_Routes('APPROPRIATEUSERNAMEHERE'));
```

and it will debug what is returned. If you like you can serialize it since it is not serialized in your class:

```
system.debug(JSON.serializePretty(BP_Routes.BP_Routes('APPROPRIATEUSERNAMEHERE')));
```

And the other answers work as well, this is just pretty easy to do without leaving org

Answer (score 4):

It will be based on the return type you are sending. For example your code is sending ResponseWrapper for HTTP-Post call with URL '/services/apexrest/BP_Routes'

Let's assume you have defined ***RepsonseWrapper*** structure as below -

```
global Class ResponseWrapper{
    public String statusCode;
    public Datetime responseOut;
    public Integer recordCount;
    public List<Map<String, String>> errorMessages;


    public ResponseWrapper(){}
}
```

***The JSON response*** would be like as below -

```
{
    "statusCode":"ERROR",
    "responseOut":"2017-04-14T01:01:01.000Z",
    "recordCount":0,
    "errorMessages":[{"errorMessage":"Some Error Message","errorCode":"SOME_ERROR_CODE"}],
}
```